# Fast way of checking whether a matrix is positive definite without Cholesky decomposition

Tags: matrices, positive-definite

I would like to check whether a matrix $A$ is positive definite. Previous answers to this question have pointed to the Cholesky decomposition. However, since my framework of choice is Tensorflow, I cannot catch and handle the exception thrown when the decomposition discovers that the matrix is not positive definite, so I need another way.

Another approach I have seen is to compute the eigenvalues, and check whether any of them are negative. This works, but it is slow. I have also heard the suggestion to compute the smallest eigenvalue. This makes sense to me -- if it is negative, we know the matrix is not positive definite -- but I am unsure how to do this efficiently. I would be grateful for some pointers!

Comment: see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1388421/reference-for-linear-algebra-books-that-teach-reverse-hermite-method-for-symmetr

Answer (score 1):

Use the Cholesky Decomp, I don't understand why you can't handle an exception. This is from Stack[Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16266720/find-out-if-matrix-is-positive-definite-with-numpy)

```
import numpy as np

    def is_pd(K):
        try:
            np.linalg.cholesky(K)
            return 1 
        except np.linalg.linalg.LinAlgError as err:
            if 'Matrix is not positive definite' in err.message:
                return 0
            else:
                raise
```

Comment: I am afraid I am using tensorflow, not numpy. Tensorflow's graph-based execution means errors cannot be handled dynamically. See: https://github.com/GPflow/GPflow/issues/553 . Also: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/10332

Comment: this is clearly an issue for stack overflow. the best choice is still cholesky because it is more computationally expensive to compute eigenvalues.

Comment: I don't know much of anything about tensorflow and why it can't handle simple errors..

Comment: or at best code review, not mathstack it isn't a question about math.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but I do think it is a math question. If there is no fast / convenient alternative to check positive definiteness, that's fine, but I would like to know if there is, hence this question.

Comment: the point about computing the smallest eigenvalue doesn't work because it computes them largest to smallest.

Comment: there is something i'm reading that event handling is done by queues in tensorflow? I've never used it.. I can't see you code..i'm not sure why you're checking if it is positive definite either..